# A global command so that some float environments are not shown at all

Tags: floats, conditionals, endfloat, newfloat

I'm using package `newfloat` to define an additional figure environment (for supplementary figures). A journal asks me to provide these in a separate document.

Ideally, I'd just need to set a variable to 0 or 1 in the header and compliation with `pdflatex` would produce a pdf file, either without the supplementary figures at all or with them at the end of the file. I'd like of course to keep the references to `labels` of my supplemetary figures working - and I'd like to keep the hyper references working too (except those to supplementary figures of course), so I believe this means avoid splitting the pdf *a posteriori* (but I'd accept a solution that preserves hyperlinks but involves a PDF splitting step using a linux command).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=los,
    listname={List of Supplementary Figures},
    name={Supplementary Figure},
    placement=tbhp,
]{suppfigure}
\usepackage[nomarkers,tablesonly,notablist]{endfloat}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor*{suppfigure}{table}
\begin{document}
There's the main figure \ref{fig.main} and 
the supplemetary one \ref{fig.supp}. 
The main one should be at the bottom of this page, 
the supplementary one in a separate pdf file.
\begin{figure}[b]
\centering\Huge{A}
\caption{Main fig}
\label{fig.main}
\end{figure}
\begin{suppfigure}[b] 
\centering\Huge{B}
\caption{Supp fig}
\label{fig.supp}
\end{suppfigure}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```

(note that I'm declaring Supp Figures as "tables" as far as `endfloat` is concerned, because it seems that package won't accept an option leaving figures in the text and putting a custom floating figure environment at the end.)

**EDIT:** I've tried to ask `endfloat` to embed delayed figures into a "blackhole" environment, but I get an error upon compilation. I've inserted in latex file preamble:

```
%% Black hole for supplementary figures
\newif\ifshowsupp
\showsupptrue
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{hidefloat}{
  \ifshowsupp
    \BODY
  \fi}
\renewcommand{\efloatpreamble}{\begin{hidefloat}}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\end{hidefloat}\begin{hidefloat}}
\renewcommand{\efloatpostamble}{\end{hidefloat}}
```

Error is "`! Argument of \hidefloat has an extra }.`" and is said to be raised when reaching `\end{document}`, although I've checked the `\efloat...` commands are called as claimed by `endfloat`. I've tried using `solution` environment from package `exsheet` and got the same result.

Comment: You could use the package pdfpages to split the pdf afterward.  The downside is I don't think it preserves hyperlinks (and since you explicitly mentioned preserving hyperlinks, I'm guessing you already knew about pdfpages).

Comment: @Teepeemm Indeed, pdfpages or pdfjam (which I think wraps pdfpages in a linux command) can do that but won't preserve links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to automatically capture all `suppfigure` environments into a new file, say, `suppfigs.tex`. This file will be built progressively during compilation with any `suppfigure`s you may use. Then, `\AtEndDocument`, you can import `suppfigs.tex` as-is, setting all the supplemental figures at the end of the document. This preserves all `\ref`erences and hyperlinking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[
    fileext=los,
    listname={List of Supplementary Figures},
    name={Supplementary Figure},
    placement=tbhp,
]{suppfigure}

\usepackage{newfile}

\newoutputstream{suppfigs}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \openoutputfile{suppfigs.tex}{suppfigs}% Create file that will store supplemental figures
  \addtostream{suppfigs}{
    % Restore way supplemental figures are handled (originally redefined to only store its contents)
    \protect\let\protect\suppfigure\protect\oldsuppfigure
    \protect\let\protect\endsuppfigure\protect\endoldsuppfigure
  }
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \closeoutputstream{suppfigs}% Close stream that should contain any supplemental figures
  \input{suppfigs}% Input gathered supplemental figures
}

\usepackage{environ}
% Despite creating supplemental figure floating environment, redefine it to just capture its contents.
% First store the original definitions (of \begin{suppfigure} and \end{suppfigure})
\let\oldsuppfigure\suppfigure
\let\endoldsuppfigure\endsuppfigure
% Redefine suppfigure to write its content to the suppfigs output stream
\RenewEnviron{suppfigure}[1][tbhp]{%
  % Within the environment we temporarily change the definition of fragile elements to \relax.
  % This ensures they won't be expanded when written to the suppfigs.tex output file.
  \let\label\relax
  \let\caption\relax
  % List other commands here that you may use that need protection from expansion (remember, this is only temporary)
  \addtostream{suppfigs}{% Write entire environment to output file
    \begin{suppfigure}[#1]
      \BODY
    \end{suppfigure}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

There's the main Figure~\ref{fig.main} and 
the supplementary one as Figure~\ref{fig.supp}. 
The main one should be at the bottom of this page, 
the supplementary one in a separate PDF file.

\begin{figure}[b]
  \centering\Huge{A}
  \caption{Main fig}
  \label{fig.main}
\end{figure}

\begin{suppfigure}[b] 
  \centering\Huge{B}
  \caption{Supp fig}
  \label{fig.supp}
\end{suppfigure}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant! This does work very well in my MWE. In the real world of my whole manuscript though, I'm getting errors when `\BODY` is being processed, `! Undefined control sequence. \BODY ...ength {\cbheight }{.3\halffig } \def \xl`(newline here) `{.3} \def \xhw {.15} \def ...`. Possibly some other package (subcaption?) generates code that is difficult to embed in the command?

Comment: @Joce: Yes, it's trying to expand `\xl` when writing to the file, and `\xl` is not defined at that point (it's being defined...). You could try adding `\let\xl\relax \let\xhw\relax` (and others) as part of the set of commands temporarily set to `\relax` within `suppfigure` to avoid their expansion. Try it and let me know; you could also post a most complete, minimal example [here](pastebin.com) and post a link to the code.